# How to expose Java method for Kafka (commitSync with partitions) in Scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka

I am trying to expose Java method via Scala (more details on original java method - it is coming from [Kafka](https://kafka.apache.org/0101/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#commitSync(java.util.Map)))

This is original Java method:

```
public void commitSync(Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> offsets)
```

How to expose and pass parameters to a method in Scala? I have something like:

```
def commitSync() = {
     consumer.commitSync(...)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The Scala snippet looks correct, however you might want to convert the collections from Java ones to Scala ones, like `java.util.Map` to `scala.collection.immutable.Map`.

However, I'm not sure what you mean by a callback to a method in Scala. Could you elaborate on what kind of callback you'd like to pass and to which method in your example above?

Comment: Can you please share a full code example? (I also want to make sure if something should go inside dots ...). I am new to Java/Scala world.. (edited question, thanks).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Scala snippet looks correct, this is how I'd fill up the rest of it:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.{KafkaConsumer, OffsetAndMetadata}
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition

import collection.mutable.Map
import collection.JavaConverters._

//initialise your consumer the way you want
val consumer = createKafkaConsumer(config, subscriptions)

//you could accept a scala.collection.mutable.Map here
def commitSync(offsets: Map[TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata]) = {
    //and then convert it to a java.util.Map
    consumer.commitSync(offsets.asJava)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! What is `.asJava` keyword? Is that necessary? Also I see `val consumer = new KafkaConsumer[K,V](Map.empty.asJava)` ,  I have it currently as `var consumer = createKafkaConsumer(config, subscriptions)`.. any thoughts on that?

Comment: Ah, sorry! I should have been a little bit more explicit with it.
`.asJava` is an implicit decorator provided by the `JavaConversions` import above.
As for the `val` vs `var`, you'd use `val` when you want an immutable value reference. i.e: you won't be able to reassign it to anything else later.

And in terms of using `createKafkaConsumer(config, subscriptions)`, that's alright. I shall modify my answer to include that. I just didn't think too much about the `new KafkaConsumer[K,V](Map.empty.asJava)` when I wrote the answer first.

Comment: Awesome! Can you be my tutor? :)

Comment: One more question - do you have example of how do you 'call' this method `def commitSync` (with parameters). I am trying to make some test case for it..